# Mapping option disappeared in Blender 2.79

Tags: properties, texture-coordinates

I'm perfectly aware of how to scale texture images, however my question is more referred to the layout of the change in the texture menu in the properties panel. In previous version of Blender, it was possible to do the mapping just by accessing Texture from the properties panel. However, in Blender 2.79 this is no longer possible and the only way to scale image textures is to manually add a mapping node in the node editor. Is it possible to get that feature back in the Texture panel? Thank you!

Comment: It would help greatly if you provide an image of the expected interface (e.g. in the previous versions of Blender) and what you get with 2.79. If you meant Mapping rollout in the Texture tab of the Properties editor then [it's still there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUbQX.jpg), you just need to select proper texture from the textures list above

Comment: Mr Zack, that's exactly what I meant. You have answered my question. I don't know why I could only see the cropping option which was also not working. I probably messed up something, I also overloaded my CPU... Now everything seems fine. Thanks again Mr Zack!!

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of the *Mapping* rollout is the same as in the previous versions. Once you have Image Texture node (not important whether with opened image or not) you will find the *Mapping* rollout in the Properties editor > Textures tab:

[image: screenshot-texture-mapping-rollout]

Note that is isn't important how the texture node was added, either from the Properties editor > Material tab or from the Node editor window.

Make sure to choose name of the Image Texture node from the drop-down list of present textures in the top of the Texture tab in the Properties editor.
E.g. if you removed any node in the Node editor window and just selected Image Texture node, its mapping options won't be shown in the Textures tab, you'll need to choose it from the list.

Note also that displayed name in the drop-down list is the name of the Image Texture node (not the label). By default it is incrementing ".001", ".002" etc. Below I renamed the nodes and copied names into the labels for clarity:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it is now in the Node-Panel for the texture (assuming you assigned it to the needed channel in the Material Context), using the Vector: and set it to e.g. "Generated" this will add a mapping Node without you seein the node editor.

Answer (score 0):

Now it is under the Brush Settings

You can find it under **Draw -> Brush Settings -> Texture.**

[image]